# Move block before Tab Magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, containers

i would like to create a banner on product view page and move this banner 
AFTER the short description and before the tab content.

[image: product view page]

I user this code under catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.banner" destination="content" after="product.info.description" />
```

but it's not working and i cannot resolve my problem.
Can someone help me solving this problem?
Best regards

The results should be the same in this picture[image: result]

TEST1:

gave me this result[image: test1]

EDIT2: My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"/>

<referenceContainer name="content">
  <container name="product.info.banner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product banner permuta">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.banner_tradein" template="Magento_Catalog::banner_tradein.phtml">
      <arguments>
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">BannerTradin</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>
  </container>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.tab.condizioni" template="Magento_Catalog::condizioni.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
      <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Condizioni</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>

<referenceContainer name="product.info.extrahint">
  <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addto" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true"/>
  </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
<move element="product.info.banner" destination="content" as="banner_tradein" after="product.info.media" before="product.info.overview"/>
```

Comment: Update your catalog_product_view.xml code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
<move element="product.info.banner" destination="product.info.details" after="product.info.description" />
```

After making changes clean your cache.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<move element="product.info.banner" destination="content" before="product.info.details"/>
```

Comment: Hi, with this solution i have the banner right before the title. Attached photo

Comment: update your layout file code

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: add your catalog_product_view.xml file code in question . I think you have already move other elements so this issue happens

Comment: May be its css issue because its overlap on other text. do inspect element and check where div is created

Answer (score 0):

Solve, css issue:

Addedd

clear:both on div and the div has been put down the description